# Update broke my external display settings - Kali

Tags: kali-linux, grub, display, firmware

I made the mistake of thinking that Kali can safely be upgraded with "apt upgrade". Clearly it can not! After reboot my external display looked like an old VGA monitor.

I have googled this a lot and all I find is feeble attempts to do this and that with X11 or Xrandr or other such blind endeavors to fix the symptoms. Nobody seems to know what the actual source of the problem is i.e. what actually broke. Was it the upgraded linux-firmware or Grub or what? I'm pretty sure it was not the kernel because I tried booting with the old kernel and I still only get 1900x1080px on the secondary display.

Can someone wiser tell me what was broken? Maybe then I can fix it.

Update: I'm not using any 3rd party drivers and both displays are correctly identified.

Update: Only error I could find in Xorg log.

```
[47.317] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
(++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
(WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[47.317] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Thu Sep 22 09:34:02 2022
[47.319] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[47.319] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[47.319] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[47.319] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[47.319] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[47.320] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
Using a default monitor configuration.
```

Update: I removed '/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-radeon.conf' but it did nothing.

Update: By scaling the external 'AOC International' display x2 I can get what looks like very blurry 4K screen.

Comment: Does `apt dist-upgrade` (equivalently, `apt full-upgrade`) fix things? That’s what you should use for upgrades on a rolling distribution, not `apt upgrade`, as [explained in the Kali documentation](https://www.kali.org/docs/general-use/updating-kali/).

Comment: Nothing to dist-upgrade.

Comment: Which xorg driver did you used before the upgrade? Which one are you using now? (check the xorg log for `EE` (errors). Usually it gives good information. Maybe you forgot to install the proprietary driver?

Comment: Why would I want to switch to proprietary driver now? I don't want closed source drivers.

Comment: Does `dmesg` show any relevant errors? What does your X.org configuration file contain?

Comment: dmesg was a good tip::: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bus: MMIO read of 00000000 FAULT at 619444 [ PRIVRING ] ::: is there a bug in Nouveau driver? Messing with Xorg.conf??? That way lies madness.

Comment: Your X logs say that you have a configuration file, that’s why I asked. Is there any more info around the “FAULT” line in `dmesg`?

Comment: I guess this needs repeating... messing with the Xorg.conf file rarely produces results since it's supposed to work automatically. Lets concentrate fixing the cause not the symptom. ie. I don't need Oxy I need to know why my head hurts... and please stop removing the name Debian from this thread. Kali = Debian.

Comment: Kali is not Debian; it is *based* on Debian, but there are enough differences that solutions which apply to one don’t necessarily apply to the other. I know that a configuration file shouldn’t be needed for X.org, but you have one, and it may be what’s causing the problem.

Comment: ┌──(root㉿kali2022)-[~]
└─# cat /etc/X11/Xwrapper.config 
# Xwrapper.config (Debian X Window System server wrapper configuration file)

Please restore the word Debian in the topic!!!

Comment: @SamTzu Please edit your post with updates instead of putting them in comments. More easily searched and comments can disappear. Kali is [not](https://www.kali.org/docs/policy/kali-linux-relationship-with-debian/) Debian. It's roughly based on Debian Testing but it has its on forked packages and its own repositories. Adding [Debian repositories](https://www.kali.org/docs/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories/) to Kali is not a good idea and is documented as a fast way to break your system. Kali != Debian.

Comment: @doneal24 - It's difficult to get Debian community here 2 help because they are directed away from this thread. PS. Never said I used Debian repos, Kali uses Debian Xwrapper. That's why I originally used word Debian in the heading (which was removed by the "help" here.)

Comment: If you're still convinced about particular packages moving downstream unchanged, you can try posting on AskUbuntu. Debian Xwrapper is included in the Ubuntu distributions so your question is as on-point there as it is here with a Debian tag.